# How to override a JMetre plugin jar in a Blazemeter Run

Tags: jar, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, blazemeter

I am trying to troubleshot an error I'm getting in Blazemeter for random-csv-data-set.

The ***btz.log***  from the Blazemeter Test run shows the below line...

```
2021-02-10 10:14:52,518 INFO o.j.r.JARSourceHTTP: Downloading: https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/blazemeter/jmeter-plugins-random-csv-data-set/0.7/jmeter-plugins-random-csv-data-set-0.7.jar
```

Which could be the point it downloads the jar (latest one?) for the required plugins for my test.

And during the test I am getting an exception from one of the classes in the plugin jar.

I have cloned the plugin project (opensource) and started adding some debug lines and compiled a new jar version.

I was advised If I upload the plugin jar along with my tests files to Blazemeter, the uploaded jar should be taken in for the run. But I still see the exception from the old line numbers which means its still referring to the original jar version 0.7.

How can I override this with my version of the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should ask this type of questions via [BlazeMeter Support](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket) as I doubt that everyone here is fully aware of what's going on there

Whatever.

Looking into [Taurus documentation](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JMeter-Location-Auto-Installation) it looks like that Random CSV Data Set Config is being detected and automatically downloaded using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/) so in order to prevent Taurus from downloading the "vanilla" version of the plugin which doesn't contain your changes you need to add the following line to your [Taurus YAML](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/) file:

```
modules:
  jmeter:
    detect-plugins: false
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitri! This was in discussion with the Blazemeter Support. However their support line responses come during US hours. So thought of Asking it here.

Comment: Just now realized , I don't have a Taurus YAML file in my projects ... Its just a jmx and couple csvs with some java classes. If I have to add a YML file, what should be the file name and format ?

Comment: I was able to get this through this way. But then I had to manage all the other dependencies by uploading them in to the test area. However the BlazemeterSupport provided me with a solution where a bash script replaces the jar V0.7 with V0.6. and the yaml script drives the bash script.